# Replace strings in text based on dictionary

Tags: r, performance, merge, dataframe

I am new to R and need suggestions.
I have a dataframe with 1 text field in it. I need to fix the misspelled words in that text field. To help with that, I have a second file (dictionary) with 2 columns - the misspelled words and the correct words to replace them.

How would you recommend doing it? I wrote a simple "for loop" but the performance is an issue.
The file has ~120K rows and the dictionary has ~5k rows and the program's been running for hours. The text can have a max of 2000 characters.

Here is the code:

```
output<-source_file$MEMO_MANUAL_TXT
for (i in 1:nrow(fix_file))  {           #dictionary file
target<-paste0(" ", fix_file$change_to_target[i], " ")
replace<-paste0(" ", fix_file$target[i], " ")
output<-gsub(target, replace, output, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: `merge`? Maybe a join with `data.table` if merge is too slow?

Comment: @joran not sure if I understand. The text could contain multiple words that require replacement. Are you suggesting it will work faster if both data files merged into one?

Comment: I'm suggesting a left join, followed by filling in the missing values from the original data frame as one might do in SQL. That is accomplished with `merge` or also using `data.table` but with different syntax. data.table might even be able to do it one go using a rolling join.

Comment: I'm not surprised that "performance is an issue." R is just not the right platform for some things.

Comment: @joran, I am still unclear how to use your suggestions. Maybe I am not properly explaining the issue. The original table has texts, like "The costomer complainied about bad service today". What I need is to find. "costomer" in second table and replace it with "customer" and then replace "complainied" with "complained". Are you suggesting creating a join based on each word in text field? (Could be 100 or more there)

Comment: I'm not at my computer to try this out now, but the `qdap()` package for text handling has `bag.of.words()` to turn a vector of multiple words into a vector of single words, and then `lookup()` to look up corrections in a data frame dictionary.  I don't know you'd turn it back into the original vector of multiple words.

Comment: It wasnt clear to me that you had strings of phrases rather than just single words.

Comment: @nacnudus, thanks! The problem is that we need to get it back to original text. (turn bag of words back into vector of multiple words)

Answer (score 2):

I would try `agrep`. I'm not sure how well it scales though.

Eg.

```
> agrep("laysy", c("1 lazy", "1", "1 LAZY"), max = 2, value = TRUE)
[1] "1 lazy"
```

Also check out `pmatch` and `charmatch` although I feel they won't be as useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, those are useful functions! I need to think a little more how to apply them in this case

Answer (score 1):

here an example , to show @joran comment using a data.table left join. It is very fast (instantaneously here).

```
library(data.table)

n1 <- 120e3
n2 <- 1e3
set.seed(1)
## create vocab
tt <- outer(letters,letters,paste0)
vocab <- as.vector(outer(tt,tt,paste0))
## create the dictionary 
dict <- data.table(miss=sample(vocab,n2,rep=F),
                   good=sample(letters,n2,rep=T),key='miss')
## the text table
orig <- data.table(miss=sample(vocab,n1,rep=TRUE),key='miss')
orig[dict]

orig[dict]
      miss good
   1: aakq    v
   2: adac    t
   3: adxj    r
   4: aeye    t
   5: afji    g
  ---          
1027: zvia    d
1028: zygp    p
1029: zyjm    x
1030: zzak    t
1031: zzvs    q
```

Comment: Text field will have multiple words (up to 2000 characters) -I am having troubles understanding how to apply your suggestion for that case.