# Looping through and replacing text in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that consists of a variable with multiple words, such as:

```
variable

"hello my name is this"

"greetings friend"
```

And another dataframe that consists of two columns, one of which is words, the other of which is replacements for those words, such as:

```
word

"hello"

"greetings"
```

replacement:

```
replacement

"hi"

"hi"
```

I'm trying to find an easy way to replace the words in "variable" with the replacement words, looping over both all the observations, and all the words in each observation. The desired result is:

```
variable

"hi my name is this"

"hi friend"
```

I've looked into some methods that use cSplit, but it's not feasible for my application (there are too many words in any given observation of "variable", so this creates too many columns). I'm not sure how I would use strsplit for this, but am guessing that is the correct option?

EDIT: From my understanding of this question, my question my be a repeat of a previously unanswered question: [Replace strings in text based on dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576783/replace-strings-in-text-based-on-dictionary)

Comment: The question you mentioned as simmilar to yours do has answer. It has two answers, actually... The answers are not accpted, but that doesn't mean they doesn't offer good solutions... Did you try already to read those codes?

Comment: Yes, I did, neither seems useful for me. I am testing the solution offered below by amrrs, and will accept if that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to @amrrs's solution, but I am using a named vector instead of supplying two separate vectors. This also addresses the issue mentioned by OP in the comments:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df2$word %>%
  paste0("\\b", ., "\\b") %>%
  setNames(df2$replacement, .) %>%
  str_replace_all(df1$variable, .)

# [1] "hi my name is this"        "hi friend"                 "hi, hellomy is not a word"
# [4] "hi! my friend"
```

This is the named vector with regex as the names and string to replace with as elements:

```
df2$word %>%
  paste0("\\b", ., "\\b") %>%
  setNames(df2$replacement, .) 
# \\bhello\\b \\bgreetings\\b 
#        "hi"            "hi"
```

**Data:**

```
df1 = data.frame(variable = c('hello my name is this',
                              'greetings friend',
                              'hello, hellomy is not a word',
                              'greetings! my friend'))

df2 = data.frame(word = c('hello','greetings'), 
                 replacement = c('hi','hi'), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**Note:**

In order to address the issue of root words also being converted, I wrapped the regex with word boundaries (`\\b`). This makes sure that I am not converting words that live inside another, like "helloguys".

Answer (score 2):

`stringr`'s `str_replace_all` would be handy in this case:

```
df = data.frame(variable = c('hello my name is this','greetings friend'))

replacement <- data.frame(word = c('hello','greetings'), replacment = c('hi','hi'), stringsAsFactors = F)

stringr::str_replace_all(df$variable,replacement$word,replacement$replacment)
```

Output:

```
> stringr::str_replace_all(df$variable,replacement$word,replacement$replacment)
[1] "hi my name is this" "hi friend"
```

Comment: I like this approach, but does it not suffer from the problem that it will replace words that start with "hello" with "hi". For instance, it might change "helloguys" to "higuys"? This isn't relevant for the example above, but is relevant to my actual application.

Comment: If that shouldn't happen, then you can add a trailing space after 'hello '. I hope that'd solve it